# Separable Differential Equation -- Last step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have separable ODE that is:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{5y(100-y)}{100}$$

I get stuck towards the end and maybe my answer is even correct,but can't see that it looks like Wolfram's answer (which I know is sometimes strange), but wanted to ask a few questions.

I separate this into:

$$dy \frac{100}{y (100-y)}=5dt$$

instead of solving the left-hand side by partial fractions, I re-write it as

$$dy \frac{100}{y^2\left(\frac{100}{y} -1\right)}$$

so that I can use the u substitution of

$$u=\frac{100}{y}-1$$
$$du = -100y^{-2} dy$$

so my left hand integral becomes

$$- \int\frac1u du$$

thus my $2$ integrals are:

$$-\int \frac1u du  = \int 5 dt$$
Solving these integrals

$$-\ln\left|\frac{100}{y} -1\right| = 5t +C.$$

Multiply by $-1$:

$$\ln \left|\frac{100}{y} -1\right| = -5t +C.$$

Here is where I'm not sure of best next step (assuming my math is correct so far)

Should I put the $\ln$ stuff into:

$$\ln\left|\frac{100-y}{y}\right|?$$

Then I would have $$\ln (100-y) - \ln y = -5t +C$$

Comment: In future, please use mathjax. I edited your question to make it readable this time, but next time, please do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for doing that.  I didn't know about mathjax.  I will use that next time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. You can get to the 'Wolfram|Alpha answer' as follows:
$$\ln\frac{100-y}{y} = -5t+c \iff \frac{100}{y}-1 = e^{-5t+c}$$
Now $e^{-5t+c} = e^c e^{-5t} = Ce^{-5t}$, so:
$$\frac{100}{y} = C e^{-5t}+1 \iff y = \frac{100}{C e^{-5t}+1}$$
Now multiply the numerator and denominator of the fraction in the RHS by $e^{5t}$:
$$y = \frac{100e^{5t}}{C+e^{5t}}$$
which is what you get on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdt%3D(5y(100-y))%2F100).

Comment: This is the classical way to solve the so-called **logistic equation** (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html)

Comment: Now I see it; thank you for showing me how Wolfram got their answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: So, what is interesting about this problem is that they DID give an initial condition of :  at time = 0 y=100  which implies in this question that C=0, which further implies that y(t) is 100.  Seems strange.

Comment: I think preferable to keep the expression $y = \frac{100}{C e^{-5t}+1}$ with one (decreasing) exponential instead of two increasing exponentials because it  reflects in a better may that there is a naturel asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree, but OP (also) asked for the steps linking his (part of the) solution to WolframAlpha's answer.

Comment: I understand...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you have written is correct:

$$\ln\left|\frac{100}{y}-1\right|=-5t+C$$

implies

$$\frac{100}{y}-1 = Ce^{-5t}$$

so

$$\frac{100}{y} = Ce^{-5t}+1,$$

and

$$\frac{100}{Ce^{-5t}+1} = y.$$

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your studies.